# Firebase getValue() returns null

Tags: android, firebase, null

So I have this code that was running just fine, "String question "  returns sometimes null and sometimes it works fine, what might be the problem?[`Data`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2aVI.png%60)

```
 Firebase localRef = new Firebase("https://commentcart.firebaseio.com/Pending Surveys/" + currUser
                            + "/" + pendingSurveyKey);


                    localRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            for (com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot d: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                String key = d.getKey();
                                String type = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(key).child("Type").getValue()).toString();
                                String question = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(key).child("Question").getValue()).toString();
                                String date = getCurrentDate();

                                surveysRefWithDates.child("Date").setValue(date);



                                switch (type)
                                {
                                    case "Free":
                                    case "Rating":

                                        String answer = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(key).child("Answer").getValue()).toString();
                                        assert key != null;
                                        surveysRef.child(key).child("Answer").setValue(answer);
                                        surveysRef.child(key).child("Type").setValue(type);
                                        surveysRef.child(key).child("Question").setValue(question);

                                        surveysRefWithDates.child(key).child("Answer").setValue(answer);
                                        surveysRefWithDates.child(key).child("Type").setValue(type);
                                        surveysRefWithDates.child(key).child("Question").setValue(question);
                                        break;

                                    case "Multiple":
                                    case "One":

                                        String option1 = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(key).child("Option1").getValue()).toString();
                                        String option2 = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(key).child("Option2").getValue()).toString();
                                        String option3 = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(key).child("Option3").getValue()).toString();

                                        surveysRef.child(key).child("Option1").setValue(option1);
                                        surveysRef.child(key).child("Option2").setValue(option2);
                                        surveysRef.child(key).child("Option3").setValue(option3);
                                        surveysRef.child(key).child("Type").setValue(type);
                                        surveysRef.child(key).child("Question").setValue(question);

                                        surveysRefWithDates.child(key).child("Option1").setValue(option1);
                                        surveysRefWithDates.child(key).child("Option2").setValue(option2);
                                        surveysRefWithDates.child(key).child("Option3").setValue(option3);
                                        surveysRefWithDates.child(key).child("Question").setValue(question);
                                        surveysRefWithDates.child(key).child("Type").setValue(type);


                                        break;

                                }
                            }

                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            mRef.child("Pending Surveys").child(currUser).child(pendingSurveyKey).removeValue()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                                            {
                                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomerOneAnswerQuestion.this);

                                                builder.setTitle(R.string.thank_you)
                                                        .setMessage(R.string.nice_day)
                                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.go_to_home, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                                                Intent goToHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerActivity.class);
                                                                goToHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                                                startActivity(goToHome);
                                                                pendingPref.edit().clear().apply();
                                                                finish();

                                                            }
                                                        });

                                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                                dialog.show();
                                            }

                                            else
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(CustomerOneAnswerQuestion.this,R.string.error_occurred,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull com.firebase.client.FirebaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You are using an extremely old version of the Firebase Android SDK.  I suggest following the instructions here to get started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start

Comment: Even with DatabaseReference the problem occurs, the code was running fine, suddenly this proble, started to occur

Answer (score 0):

`getValue` returns null where there is no data at the location of your query.  Check the value of `currUser` and `pendingSurveyKey` and make sure you are actually querying data that exists at the location you're building.

Comment: I have debugged everything and the values are correct, it's not the first time I work with firebase I have implemented many projects but this is the first time I face this problem, what makes me crazy is that sometimes it works just fine although the input is always the same

Comment: Since we can't see the values you're passing to Firebase, there's nothing we can do.  You're probably doing something wrong.  Firebase doesn't just "suddenly stop working".  Your question should include the exact values of all variables that you're passing, as well as the screenshot of the data that matches.

Comment: I think the problem is now solved, I spent days debugging and the values are always different than null but now after using DatabaseReference again it's working just fine..

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just solved the problem thank to @DougStevenson, although I was using DatabaseReference and I don't know why it was crashing but now it works fine..